# Angular App with many event handlers, events seem to have large overhead?

Tags: javascript, angular, optimization, mouseevent

I am creating a website using Angular 5 that is essentially a GUI for creating a type of document.

I am using SVG to draw the document and the nature of the document structure means that I end up with a lot of elements, in a large document it can have ~20,000 DOM elements on the page (mostly the SVG). Many of the SVG elements have event handlers on them such as `mousedown`, `mouseenter`, `click`. Probably totals a few thousand event handlers.

Not entirely unexpectedly, performance is getting quite bad on large documents and I am trying to improve it. I have been using the chrome performance monitor to try to find out why, and it seems that the event handlers are responsible. I can see that for almost every event handler that is triggered, the time is at least ~70ms. For example this is just when mousing over an area of the document:

[image]

The actual code called by these event handlers is doing essentially nothing (it's surrounded by an if statement that is false), and when timing it via console.time I can see it takes <1ms.

So what is taking 70+ ms and can I do anything about it?

When the document is small these same events only take ~8ms but it seems the more event handlers there are, the slower they are?

Comment: Please share some sample code to test on

Comment: Seems like your integrated Angular change detection strategies are causing the issue. This is common. Many times this is the result of tons of components with inputs loaded. Check out change detection strategies with OnPush and a general explanation here: https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/02/22/angular-2-change-detection-explained.html

Comment: @ShellNinja been reading about that and I think it's the right track, thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With a better understanding of angular change detection thanks to the link ShellNinja provided (https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/02/22/angular-2-change-detection-explained.html) I found my issue was:

- Angular running change detection every time an event is triggered
- Due to the large size of my document/model each of these events were taking a noticeable amount of time and making the page appear laggy

I fixed this performance issue by:

- Splitting my document into smaller components (previously the entire document was 1 component, now it is ~50 smaller ones)
- Setting the change detection strategy on these components to `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` so that events in that component only trigger change detection on that one component instead of the entire document

Now these event handlers take much less time and the page feels responsive again